# Extending Python Enum but preserving type hints

Tags: python, enums

How can I extend an Enum type in Python 3.9 with a classmethod and preserving the typehints?

For example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from enum import Enum

from aenum import extend_enum


class FormattingType(str, Enum):
    DECIMAL = 'decimal'
    

class NewType(str, Enum):
    UNKNOWN = 'Unknown'

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value: object) -> NewType:
        return cls.UNKNOWN

[extend_enum(NewType, i.name, i.value) for i in FormattingType]

def foo(arg1: NewType) -> None:
    if arg1 == NewType.UNKNOWN:
        print('Unknown')
    if arg1 == NewType.DECIMAL:
        print('Decimal')
```

mypy complains:

```
scratch.py:23: error: "Type[NewType]" has no attribute "DECIMAL"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Would be possible to perhaps create a new Type extending all options or changing the `annotations` attribute from the `NewType` class to be in compliance with mypy?

I'm also open to suggestions that extend or create an Enum class `NewType` with the `_missing_` class method, having all the values from the Enum `FormattingType` with or without using the `aenum` package.